# Choose destination of a folder reference

Tags: xcode4

I think this should be an easy question about Xcode 4, I've got a specific folder reference and I want to customize where it gets copied to the bundle, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Copy Files build phase to the target. Add your folder to the build phase.

To add a Copy Files build phase in Xcode 4, select the project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select your target from the left side of the editor. Click the Build Phases build at the top of the editor. Click the Add Build Phase button at the bottom of the editor and choose Add Copy Files.